# Lyrics for additional verses in LilyPond?

Tags: lilypond

Is there a way in LilyPond to simply list the lyrics corresponding to
additional verses after the end of the music, with one paragraph per verse?

(N.B. This exact question has been [asked before](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-music/2001-03/msg00089.html), in 2001, but the first answer ("read this book") references a dead URL, while the second (use `\context Lyrics`) does not work for me, I get LilyPond syntax errors.)

Here's the song under which I want to write the additional verses.

```
\header{
  title = "JOHN BALL"
  instrument = "(for unaccompanied voice)"
  composer = "Sydney Carter"
  copyright = "From \"In the Present Tense (Songs of Sydney Carter Book 5)\", Stainer and Bell 1982, ISBN 9780852495001"
  tagline = ""
}

\score {
  \relative {
    \time 2/4
    \clef treble
    \tempo 4=120
    \key a \major
    cis'' a8 fis |  e4. cis8 |  d e gis fis |  e2 | 
    fis4 fis8 fis | fis4 gis8 a | b a gis a | b cis d b | 
    cis4 a8 fis |  e4. cis8 |  d e gis fis |  e4 a8 gis | 
    fis4 fis8 fis | d' cis b a | gis2 | a \bar "||"
    b4 b |  b4. cis8 |  b a gis fis |  e2 | b'4 b8 cis |  d( cis ) b a | cis2 | b4 e8 d | 
    cis4 a8 fis | e4 cis | d8 e gis fis | e4 a8 gis | fis4 fis8 fis | d' cis b a | gis2 |  a \bar "|."
  }
  \addlyrics { 
    Who'll be the | la -- dy, | Who will be the | lord, | When we are | 
    ruled by the | love of one an -- | o -- ther? Tell me, | Wholl be the | 
    la -- dy, | Who will be the | lord, In the | light that is | 
    com -- ing in the | morn -- | ing. | 
    Sing, John | Ball, And | tell it to them | all: | Long live the | day that is | 
    dawn -- | ing! And I'll | crow like a | cock, I'll | car -- ol like a | lark, For the | 
    light that is | com -- ing In the | morn -- | ing. }

  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}

\version "2.18.2"
```

(Sorry about the [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/178985), `<!-- language: lang-lilypond -->` is not yet supported in the Google Code Prettyfier that SE uses.)

I'd like to add verses 2, 3, and 4 underneath, separated from the music  just as words, like here:

[image: Verses under a score]

Comment: This is cross-posted from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34827587/575530) and possibly the mailing list. I'm confused about where questions like this should go (and my confusion is cross-posted [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314849/575530) and [here](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/2363/2125)!)

Answer (score 7):

I got an answer from [Knute Snortum](http://snortum.net/) on the LiliyPond mailing list [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.lilypond.general/109326)

After my `score` block I can add a `markup` block like this

```
\markup {
    \column {
        \line { \null }
        \line { 2. Here I go }
    }
}
```

It turns out that this is covered in the LilyPond documentation ([printing stanzas at the end](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/stanzas#printing-stanzas-at-the-end)) but they use the term 'stanza' and so my searching for 'verse' did not lead me there.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use lytex, i.e., latex with lilypond

`lilypond-book yoursong.lytex ; latex yoursong.tex; dvips -Ppdf yoursong.dvi ; ps2pdf yoursong.ps`

with a lytex file such as

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\lilypondfile{yoursong.ly}

\begin{verse}
The first line \\
The second line
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

I suppose that there might be font issues. At least in the setup I have so far the fonts look different.